# Resultados de la elección de moderadores, 2019

Tags: soporte, elecciones

[La segunda elección de moderadores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/2) de Stack Overflow en español ha terminado y los votos han sido calculados.  Los nuevos moderadores del sitio son:

[image: Pikoh] [image: gbianchi]

Ellos se unirán al [grupo de moderadores existentes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) - por favor démosles las gracias por otorgarnos su tiempo y talento. También ofrezcámosles nuestro apoyo y asistencia mientras entran en este nuevo rol.

Para encontrar más detalles sobre cómo fue el proceso de votación, puedes [descargar los resultados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/2) o [ver el resumen online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5074301801725952/0).

Comment: ¡Enhorabuena! Bienvenidos como nuevos moderadores del sitio.

Comment: Bienvenidos!!!!

Comment: <3 Gracias por la confianza a todos...

Comment: Bienvenidos, a mi parecer, los mejores para el puesto!

Comment: Enhorabuena a ambos

Comment: Enhorabuena nuevos moderadores!

Comment: ¡Enhorabuena Pikoh y gbianchi! Qué bueno teneros de moderadores. Y gracias al resto por presentarse, ¡competíais con candidatos muy potentes!

Comment: Muy buena elección. Felicidades a ambos, sé que harán un excelente trabajo y que SO irá a mejor, sin omitir que los que hasta ahora han sido moderadores también lo han hecho muy bien.

Comment: Felicitaciones Pikoh y gbianchi!!!!

Comment: Felicidades a ambos. Mis respetos

Comment: Muhcas facilidades a Pikoh y gbianchi . Espreo qeu soberllevéis la prseión dle crago con fureza y dilgiencia.

Comment: Felicitaciones a ambos, muchos éxitos en su nueva labor.

Comment: Que alegría tenerlos como moderadores :D sé que harán un gran trabajo, paciencia y buen humor, las mejores vibras lml

Comment: Felicidades pikoh.

Comment: Felicidades chavales

Answer (score 33):

Muchas gracias por la parte que me toca por las felicitaciones :)

Espero estar a la altura de lo requerido para ser vuestro moderador, y aprovecho para pediros un poco de paciencia conmigo al principio. No sabeis el montón de juguetitos nuevos que trae el rol de moderador electo ;)

Afortunadamente, contaré con la experiencia de nuestros 3 moderadores antiguos (que no viejos, para eso ya estoy yo) para que me guien y ayuden en la labor.

De nuevo gracias por la confianza depositada.

Answer (score 33):

Mil gracias por la confianza!!!

Como bien dice mi archienemigo Pikoh ( :p ), tenemos tantos botones nuevos que no sabemos por donde empezar...

Sean pacientes, todos seran atendidos a su debido tiempo...

Por suerte nada es tan grave como parece, y el sitio esta muy bien cuidado por todos los que participan y por los moderadores que ya venian haciendo un gran trabajo...

Comment: ¡Felicitaciones, justo y merecido!

Answer (score 2):

**Mil felicidades!! a los dos, en buena hora eh...**

Sabemos el trabajo es arduo y que no sera fácil pero también se sabe que lo harán bien, suerte y **muchas gracias** por el bien que hacen a la comunidad.