# ¡Feliz año nuevo 2020!

Tags: soporte

Muchas gracias a [@Alvaro Montoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/250/alvaro-montoro) por la traducción.

---

El año que termina fue ajetreado y bastante difícil tanto para la comunidad como para la empresa. Este año completamos juntos con éxito varias iniciativas increíblemente importantes:

- [Elegimos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4050/10) dos moderadores [@Pikoh](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15301/pikoh), [@gbianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi).
- Discutimos y añadimos los artículos con “[los valores fundamentales](/help/key-values)” y “[el manifiesto](/help/manifesto)” al centro de ayuda.
- Organizamos algunos concursos.

¡Y mucho más! ¡Sigamos así!

#### El año en números

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------
|                    | Stack Overflow     |  Stack Overflow   |
|                    | en español         |  en español       |
|                    | 2018               |  2019             |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Preguntas         |     50 176         |    49 726         |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Respuestas        |     44 573         |    40 739         |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Nuevos usuarios   |     39 181         |    38 608         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### Algunas ideas sobre el futuro

- *Más atención a los comentarios de los usuarios*. Como puedo ver, [la compañía ha tomado un curso seguro para mejorar la experiencia de participación en el sitio](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/). Es muy importante que hagamos mejoras basadas en los comentarios de la comunidad. Aunque confiamos en las ideas de los usuarios para tomar decisiones desde el primer día, este año habrá más oportunidades para compartir vuestras opiniones sobre el sitio. Si alguna vez pensaste en algo que cam biar el sitio, ¡parece un buen momento para realizar esos planes!
- *Webcasts, meetups de comunidad, concursos* y otras iniciativas para "crear una comunidad". Creo que sería genial organizar más de esos eventos en el nuevo año.
- *Centrarlos en la misión del proyecto*. Si podemos evitar efectivamente todo (lo bueno y lo malo) que trata de cambiar el foco en nuestra misión (crear una comunidad de conocimiento) el sitio crecerá más rápido y la experiencia de participación será más agradable. Una manera de conseguir esto es elegir un objetivo ambicioso y hacer todo los posible para lograrlo.

En la última década el mundo de las TI ha cambiado mucho: en 2010, llevaba varios días averiguar como construir un proyecto de "Hola Mundo" para la primera versión de Android OS, hoy uno puede escribir una app para un vehículo en JavaScript con streaming de música desde una red social en cuestión de horas. Estoy increíblemente encantado de darme cuenta que por más de 4 años hemos sido un catalizador de esos cambios positivos al 100%. ¡Muchas gracias a todos por ello! =)

#### ¡Stack Overflow somos nosotros! ¡Felicitémonos!

¡Únete a las celebraciones! Por favor comparte los momentos más agradables y positivos en la vida de la comunidad que recuerdes personalmente. Si durante el último año algún usuario hizo tu vida mejor, por favor, no dudes en felicitarlos diciendo "Gracias" en una respuesta a esta pregunta. Estoy seguro que los usuarios estarán muy contentos por el detalle.

[image: Christmas Tree]

*¡Muchas gracias a cada usuario de [Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)! ¡Feliz Año Nuevo! ¡Os deseamos todo lo mejor y nos alegrará veros a todos en el Año Nuevo! ¡Hay muchas cosas interesantes esperándonos a todos! =)*

Comment: !Feliz Año Nuevo!

Answer (score 10):

Tenemos  muchos usuarios nuevos pero **hay menos preguntas en 2019 que en 2018**. Me parece muy preocupante ese dato.

Pero aún más preocupante es el hecho de que tenemos **muchas menos respuestas**.

We have many new users in SOes, but in total **we asked less questions** than last year, that's not good.
But even worse: **the number of answers is much lower than it should be**!

Comment: Particularmente noto que las respuestas emitidas no siempre reciben aceptación, y los autores "abandonan" la pregunta sin mencionar si ha sido útil o no la colaboración.
Por lo menos para mí, estas situaciones no me motivan a seguir colaborando con nuevas preguntas, si no he recibido aceptación o rechazo de mis respuestas.

Comment: Quizás es una incoherencia lo que diga, pero igual quiero aportar mi comentario para ver si puedo ser fuente de una idea útil, un sitio web de ejemplo donde se ha podido reducir dramáticamente este incidente es YouTube, me refiero en si a los "likes", en mi opinión, se podría tomar como inspiración varios de los factores que hacen que un usuario, le de importancia a un sistema de votación.

Comment: Por ejemplo, yo al ser usuario de dicha pagina entiendo la relevancia que tienen para los youtubers un like de mi parte, pero no es sino por ellos mismos, que soy consciente de esto, tal vez sin no fuéramos tan inflexibles con las redacciones en SO, podríamos concientizar a otros usuarios a hacerlo, a traves por ejemplo de firmas digitales, podría agregarse como firma de quien responde. para no estorbar entre la respuesta y la pregunta. Algo como 
Firma: "Recuerda votar si esta respuesta te ha servido ;)"

Comment: @IsLiz lo que comentas ya existe en la plataforma [checa este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Como nuevo usuario (aún que lleve un tiempo registrado), yo si sigo mis preguntas, y las de otros. Soy estudiante y aún no me veo capacitado para formular respuestas válidas. Opino que sólo aquellos con reales ganas de aprender seguirán las respuestas a sus preguntas, indiferentemente del sistema de puntuación. Alguna pregunta mía se quedó en el olvido hace tiempo y la acababa respondiendo yo cuando lograba la respuesta (que ojo, también es válido). Así que no creo que sea un problema, vivimos en un mundo dónde lo queremos todo de forma inmediata, los más jóvenes no tienen paciencia.

Comment: @Ramón El problema no es que haya menos respuestas que preguntas (que también es un poco triste). El problema es que el número de respuestas este año es mucho menor, el ratio respuestas/preguntas ha bajado alarmantemente. Lo normal es que se mantenga o se mejore (más gente, más conocimientos), pero parece que la gente está dejando de responder. Solo 37 personas han conseguido más de 2500 puntos de reputación en 2019. A *al menos 250 puntos* no han llegado más que 1300. Es una participación muy baja

Comment: Puede ser que no sepan la respuesta y se abstienen de responder, ya que las preguntas solucionadas ya están respondidas, entonces las que no están respondidas nadie sabe la solución.

Comment: Yo uso stackoverflow en ingles, pero por casualidad acabe aqui y ya que estaba, respondi a una pregunta. Aun no se si le ha sido de ayuda o no, porque la persona no me ha respondido. Pues la verdad es que se quitan las ganas de responder. No ya por los puntos, pero al menos un comentario, que es tiempo que perdemos tambien los que respondemos y si lo hacemos es porque nos gusta ver que ayudamos, sin feedback no sabemos si ha servido para algo lo que hemos dicho.

Comment: @PabloLozano Sábes como le ha ido a stackoverflow en inglés y en que se diferencia a esta (la de español), además de ser más grande en todo sentido claro. Pero por ahí tiene alguna particularidad que la de nuestro idioma no posee.

Comment: Un par de apreciaciones personales... - A medida que conozco la comunidad, pregunto menos pero busco y leo más. -Tengo colegas que solo usan SO para consulta. Desde este punto de vista, no veo tan malo que bajen los indicadores de preguntas y respuestas. Ahora, si baja el indicador de acceso al sitio, eso si sería preocupante.